# get value FieldObject CrystalReport vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

i want to get the value off a fieldObject after generate the report for example :
i want to store  the number of pages in a variable using Vb.net

```
dim nbpage as FieldObject
total_page = CType(report.Section2.ReportObjects("totalPage"), FieldObject)
```

i want to get the value ,i'm very blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can get information about last page , page number....using this code :

```
 Dim iPageCount As Integer = report.FormatEngine.GetLastPageNumber(New ReportPageRequestContext())
```

it solve the problem